# Display custom mesh on Canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

Hey i want to draw some custom meshes on a Canvas object in my scene. The Canvas uses Render Mode World Space. I wrote a simple script creating a rectangle mesh based on the Canvas dimensions. It works when using a MeshFilter and MeshRenderer but i want to draw it directly onto the canvas. I tried using CanvasRenderer.SetMesh() but nothing appears.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshCanvas : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3[] vertices;
    int[] triangles;
    Mesh mesh;

    float canvasHeigt;
    float canvasWidth;

    public float offset = 10f;

    private void Update()
    {
        canvasHeigt = FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height;
        canvasWidth = FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width;

        vertices = new Vector3[]
        {
            new Vector3(0 + offset, 0 + offset),
            new Vector3(0 + offset, canvasHeigt - offset),
            new Vector3(canvasWidth - offset, canvasHeigt - offset),
            new Vector3(canvasWidth - offset, 0 + offset)
        };

        triangles = new int[]
        {
            0, 1, 2,
            2, 3, 0
        };

        mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        this.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a material on the `CanvasRenderer` to see your mesh.

```
// this.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh; // not necessary

Material material = ...  // get your mat

CanvasRenderer cr = GetComponent<CanvasRenderer>();
cr.materialCount = 1;
cr.SetMaterial(material, 0);
cr.SetMesh(mesh);
```

Comment: I can now see my mesh but it doesnt matter what material i choose the lightning is always broken. I tried applying a material to a Plane on the Canvas and its also broken. As soon as i swap the CanvasRenderer with a MeshRenderer no lightning issues appear. That means my material and my mesh normals are fine and the problem is the CanvasRenderer right?

Comment: Sry, i cant reproduce your problem with your code sample and a test scene. Plane with material looks fine for me (lights included). Sounds like a new question to me with more details needed what exactly is "broken".

Comment: ok i asked a new question thx